# javafx is not recognized after installing jdk 7u9

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I installed jdk 7u9 and added it to the build path of an eclipse Java project.
However, when I'm trying to import some javafx classes eclipse can't recognize them:

```
       import javafx.scene.media.Media;
```

I read at Oracle's website (and a lot of other websites) that javafx is already included in jdk 7u9 and there is no need to install any additional addons.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Use [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/)

Comment: I found some work around. I'm sure it's not a good solution but so far it's working.
I downloaded and installed the javafx for JDK 6 and I added its jar manually.
Now javafx is visible in Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 1):

The jfxrt.jar is in the jre/lib folder of your jdk, but not on the default boot classpath. That is why Eclipse won't add it to the "JRE System libraries".

The issue is tracked [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7166330).
The fix will be made in Java 8.

You should add the jar manually to the project build path or use [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) and setup a JavaFX Project.